# Could not start docker with existing LVM thin pool option

Tags: docker, lvm, thinpool

I created an LVM thin pool to be used by Docker for storage. At the docker start time, I tell it to use the thin pool. Everything worked as expected by running `docker info` , I noted that it is using that thinpool of 32 GB.

Now the problem is that, when I stopped and killed the Docker process and cleaned up `/var/lib/docker` and want to start everything from clean state, the docker daemon couldn't start with the previous thinpool option, resulting in some transaction id error for the thin pool.

So I deleted and created the thinpool again and this time it worked fine. Therefore, the question is, will I have to create a brand new thin pool each time I have to restart Docker? Or do I need to do some clean up for the existing thin pool so that I can reuse it again?

Docker 1.10 on CentOS 7

`WARN[0000] containerd: low RLIMIT_NOFILE changing to max  current=1024 max=4096
ERRO[0001] devmapper: Open Transaction id 1 is less than pool transaction id 83

ERRO[0001] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "devicemapper" failed: devmapper: Base Device UUID and Filesystem verification failed.devmapper: Current Base Device UUID:40110cf6-3c7a-4d3c-aa6a-8ed3e9d54c31 does not match with stored UUID:83b9b9b0-1e77-4b0f-867a-ceda73854821. Possibly using a different thin pool than last invocation

FATA[0001] Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devmapper: Base Device UUID and Filesystem verification failed.devmapper: Current Base Device UUID:40110cf6-3c7a-4d3c-aa6a-8ed3e9d54c31 does not match with stored UUID:83b9b9b0-1e77-4b0f-867a-ceda73854821. Possibly using a different thin pool than last invocation 
`

Comment: Can you provide the error you are receiving? Also the Docker, OS, & kernel versions?

Comment: i am using docker 1.10 , on centos7

Comment: Question updated with error message

Comment: look this https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/16092

Comment: @Emmanuel that seems to be entierly diffrent thinpool problem with docker

Comment: "Docker will not take ownership of the specified thin-pool device unless it has 0 data blocks used and a transaction id of 0. This should help guard against using a thin-pool that is already in use." This seems to be related to the first error message

Comment: But in my case , the thin-pool is not in use , the previous process is killed. and if it still saying in use , then the only way i see , is to delete the thinpool and re-create it? that was my question